# During an ongoing build, what is the criteria used by `docker image prune` to classify an image as dangling?

Tags: docker, docker-image

On my PC, in one window suppose if a large docker build is in progress (about 30 layers). While the build is in progress (say it has reached on the 20th layer), in another window suppose I run `docker image prune -a -f` (goal is to remove dangling and unused images), then will the layers of the build that are in progress be considered as dangling and removed causing the build to fail? Is this deterministic behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker image prune -a -f` command will delete all images, including tagged images, so not just the dangling ones (this is the `-a` option). There is likely a race condition in that process depending on where the build is at the time the prune command scans for in use images. If the build is currently inside of a `RUN` step and using the image, then the prune should skip all of the layers used by that image.

If you are between `RUN` steps when the prune command looks for images to delete, it may attempt to delete the image being used as the parent in your build. That will likely error out the prune if during the delete that image is then in use again. However, it could also cause an error in the build if that prune deletes the parent image the build expected to extend.

Typically I'd recommend against doing a prune where you expect the images cleaned up will include those being actively used in builds. You will cause builds to take a longer time as deleted images are downloaded against, and you may cause more space used on the registry and other nodes pulling images if the layers are recreated rather than reusing the cached layers from previous builds.

For an active build server, using buildkit with it's built in garbage collection is a much better option. The garbage collection looks at when a layer was used rather than originally created, and is based on size of the layers so you can allocate a specific amount of disk for your image builds. And since buildkit runs on containerd instead of the docker engine directly, the cache itself is not mixed with the docker images and you can prune images without impacting the build cache. There's an example of these garbage collection options in [my DockerCon presentation](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#buildkit).

Comment: How come there is no official documentation about this scenario to understand what can happen diterministically?

Comment: @variable the documentation is open to PR's. I've never seen anyone else ask this question so not sure it makes sense to spend time documenting.